# declaration of constant strings in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Today, while declaring constant strings (using Visual Studio community 2015 in win 10 ) I was facing a problem.
Book said,

```
String BYTE "HELLO",0
```

while I typed in the same, MASM throws errors like:

> syntax error : ,

Then, I removed , and 0 then it showed:

> Missing operator in expression

How can I eliminate this error?
What is the right way to declare a constant string?

Comment: What book are you reading? Perhaps it is not teaching you MASM syntax? `BYTE` is illegal here (although it is a keyword used other places). This should be `String db "HELLO",0` and probably located in a `.data` segment.

Comment: @Cody Gray  I am reading x86 assembly programming by kip Irvine. Your notation is given under legacy data directives and as equally correct.It is indeed in the .data segment. Thank you.

Comment: My problem fixed but rather weirdly.. after updating my PC and rebooting..  it is now accepting both the notations. But what is the standard notation supported by most assemblers?  THANK YOU.

Comment: There are no 'most assemblers'. Everyone has its own syntax.  For MASM, the line should be `String db "HELLO",0`.

Comment: a modern version of MASM does support also `BYTE` directive (as replacement for old good `DB`), and indeed `DB` is now "obsolete"... I expect to have plenty of fun with MASM questions on SO in next decade, as if ambiguity between 16/32/64b mode and MASM/TASM vs NASM/FASM/YASM vs gas/AT&T wasn't already enough... Well played MS, well played. :D

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The version of MASM included with Visual Studio 2015 assembles `String BYTE "HELLO",0` without errors.

Answer (score 8):

The "standard" MASM syntax for declaring a constant string is:

```
VarName DB "String Contents",0
```

This declares an array of bytes (`db` == *d*eclare *b*yte) with the symbolic name `VarName`. The contents of that array are given by the value enclosed in quotation marks (`"String Contents"`), and the array is terminated by a NUL character (`0`). Obviously, what this gives you is a standard C-style NUL-terminated string that can be used with almost any C API.

I call this the "standard" syntax for MASM because it's the one I use, the one that most compilers/disassemblers use, and the one that you'll see most code samples written in.

However, as [Ped7g points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489203/declaration-of-constant-strings-in-x86-assembly-language#comment70202874_41489203), modern versions of MASM actually support using the `BYTE` directive in the declaration. It is effectively a synonym for `DB`. That would make the book author's code correct, and suitable for use with the version of MASM bundled with any modern version of Visual Studio:

```
VarName BYTE "String Contents",0
```

You can use either one you want. If you're learning from a book that uses the latter, you may want to stick with it for convenience. However, you should be aware of the former, too, since as I mentioned, you'll see it all over the place.

---

Here is the complete list of type specifiers (keywords) that you'll see in data definitions:

- **`DB`**(*D*eclare *B*yte), which is equivalent to **`BYTE`**
  (an **8-bit** value the same size as the `AL` register)
- **`DW`** (*D*eclare *W*ord), which is equivalent to **`WORD`**
  (a **16-bit** value the same size as the `AX` register)
- **`DD`** (*D*eclare *D*oubleWord), which is equivalent to **`DWORD`**
  (a **32-bit** value the same size as the `EAX` register)
- **`DF`** (*D*eclare *F*loat), which is equivalent to **`FWORD`**
  (a **48-bit** value used to store a single-precision floating-point value)
- **`DQ`** (*D*eclare *Q*uadWord), which is equivalent to **`QWORD`**
  (a **64-bit** value the same size as the `RAX` register when targeting 64-bit mode x86-64, and also used to store a double-precision floating-point value)
- **`DT`** (*D*eclare *T*en-byte), which is equivalent to **`TBYTE`**
  (an **80-bit** value the same size as the x87 FPU's stack-based registers; used to spill a value from there directly to memory without losing precision)

Comment: Do you have a citation for DB standing for *Declare* Byte?  I think of it as standing for "Data Byte"; its purpose is to assemble bytes directly into the output file.

Comment: No citation on hand, @Peter. Just consistency, the hobgoblin of my simple mind.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are a few ways to declare a string in MASM:
First, you can declare the string in the data segment and use the variable throughout your code.

```
stringName    BYTE   "Hello, this is a string", 0
```

To declare a string constant you can use the EQU or TEXTEQU directive. Both are declared before the data segment in the global scope.

```
constantString  EQU      <"Hello, string content", 0>
```

The tricky part, is that you then need to declare a variable in data segment that has the value of constant. Like this:

```
.data
variableName    BYTE    constantString
```

Then you can go on to use your named variable in the rest of the code.

The TEXTEQU can be a bit trickier. It creates a 'text macro'. It can simply assign the text, assign the contents of another existing text macro, or a const integer expression. For the example, here is the text. Again, the constant must be assigned to a variable in the data segment.

```
constantName    TEXTEQU    <"string content">

.data
variableName    BYTE   constantName
```

Hope this helps. Note: the zero byte at the end of the string is important for a string declaration, but in the TEXTEQU you are defining a MACRO, not just a string.

Comment: `TEXTEQU` is an assemble-time directive, like `#define` in C.  It doesn't assemble any bytes into the output file.

Comment: Are the `<` and `>` around the data actually needed for EQU or TEXTEQU to work?  I don't think that looks like normal MASM syntax.

Comment: yes, but usually strings are declared in the .data segment. When the < > are used, the constants are declared in the global scope